# php session error

Tags: session, session-variables, session-state, php

I was trying to make a shopping cart and got a code from web..

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once 'class/Item.php';
$product_id = $_REQUEST['i_id'];
$action = $_REQUEST['action']; 

$item= new Item();

if($product_id && !$item->productExists($product_id)) {
    die("Error. Product Doesn't Exist");
}

switch($action) { 
    case "add":
        $_SESSION['cart'][$product_id]++; 
    break;

    case "remove":
        $_SESSION['cart'][$product_id]--; 
        if($_SESSION['cart'][$product_id] == 0) unset($_SESSION['cart'][$product_id]); 
    break;

    case "empty":
        unset($_SESSION['cart']); 
    break;
}
?>
```

but durring adding the first item to the cart it goes error. How can I correct it.

Error:

> Notice: Undefined index: cart in C:\wamp\www\website\store_esp\addtocart.php  on line 16
>
> Notice: Undefined index: 2 in C:\wamp\www\website\store_esp\addtocart.php on line 16

Comment: Maybe referencing a nonexistant associative array member is the mistake?

Comment: Probably an `undefined index` warning.  I'm thinking `$_SESSION['cart'][$product_id]++;` is likely the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you may be trying to manipulate variables that aren't setup yet.  Make sure you're checking that `$_SESSION['cart'][$product_id]` exists before you do something on it:

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['cart'][$product_id]))
  $_SESSION['cart'][$product_id] = 0;

switch($action) {
...
```

Comment: He would also need to change `if($_SESSION['cart'][$product_id] == 0) unset...` to `if($_SESSION['cart'][$product_id] <= 0) unset...`.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing this:

```
$_SESSION['cart'][$product_id]++;
```

to this:

```
if (isset($_SESSION['cart'][$product_id])) {
    ++$_SESSION['cart'][$product_id];
} else {
    $_SESSION['cart'][$product_id] = 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing the error, it's impossible to tell for sure.  But using my deductive powers, I think the problem is here:

```
$_SESSION['cart'][$product_id]++;
```

It should be this:

```
if (isset($_SESSION['cart'][$product_id])) {
    $_SESSION['cart'][$product_id]++;
} else {
    $_SESSION['cart'][$product_id] = 1;
}
```

And you need to change this:

```
session_start();
// add this part
if (!isset($_SESSION['cart'])) {
    $_SESSION['cart'] = array();
}
require_once 'class/Item.php';
$product_id = $_REQUEST['i_id'];
$action = $_REQUEST['action'];
```